# Creating a new email message using the default email program

Tags: winapi

How can I programatically open a new message window in the default email client (such as Outlook) using Windows API calls?  I will need to include an attachment and would prefer to specify the default message body in 'rich text' (ie. not plain) format.

Comment: The attachment option in the mailto: protocol has been removed from all emailers quite a while ago.  Rampant abuse.  You'll need to use the emailer's automation interface to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ShellExecute solution is good for simple messages without attachments, but if you want more control over the process, you may try the [MAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/windows/desktop/windowsmapi/mapi-stub-library-and-simple-mapi); in particular, see the [MAPISendMail](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/mapi/nc-mapi-mapisendmail) function and the [MapiMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/mapi/ns-mapi-mapimessage) structure.

For even more complex needs, there's the extended MAPI, but I didn't find any documentation about it on the MSDN. However [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10881/MAPIEx-Extended-MAPI-Wrapper) seems to be a good wrapper around the extended MAPI.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this using the [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx). An attachment should be used as parameter: something like this but I don't remember for sure:  "mailto:email@something?subject=subject&body=body&attachment=..."

Comment: I think that should be HTTP-style query parameters: `mailto:email@something?subject=subject&body=body&attachment=...`

Comment: Newer versions of Outlook now throw an error on the &attachment parameter.